# Is there a more memory efficient way to search through a Core Data database?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, memory-management

I need to see if an object that I have obtained from a CSV file with a unique identifier exists in my Core Data Database, and this is the code I deemed suitable for this task:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity;
entity = 
[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ICD9"
            inManagedObjectContext:passedContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uniqueID like %@", uniqueIdentifier];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];
NSError *err;
NSArray* icd9s = [passedContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err];
[fetchRequest release];
if ([icd9s count] > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < [icd9s count]; i++) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
        NSString *name = [[icd9s objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"uniqueID"];
        if ([name caseInsensitiveCompare:uniqueIdentifier] == NSOrderedSame && name != nil)
        {
            [pool release];
            return [icd9s objectAtIndex:i];
        }
        [pool release];
    }
}
return nil;
```

After more thorough testing it appears that this code is responsible for a huge amount of leaking in the app I'm writing (it crashes on a 3GS before making it 20 percent through the 1459 items). I feel like this isn't the most efficient way to do this, any suggestions for a more memory efficient way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

- Don't use the `like` operator in your request predicate.  Use `=`.  That should be much faster.
- You can specify the case insensitivity of the search via the predicate, using the `[c]` modifier.
- It's not necessary to create and destroy an `NSAutoreleasePool` on each iteration of your loop.  In fact, it's probably not needed at all.
- You don't need to do any of the checking inside the `for()` loop.  You're duplicating the work of your predicate.

So I would change your code to be:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:...];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uniqueID =[c] %@", uniqueIdentifier]];
NSError *err = nil;
NSArray *icd9s = [passedContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err];
[fetchRequest release];
if (error == nil && [icd9s count] > 0) {
  return [icd9s objectAtIndex:0]; //we know the uniqueID matches, because of the predicate
}
return nil;
```

Comment: You may also want to assert that, when `count` returns greater than 0, it returns exactly 1. Returning more than one match for an ostensibly-unique ID suggests database corruption, probably by bad logic elsewhere in the program. You should also test whether the array, not the error object, is `nil`, as documented in the Error-Handling Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC

Comment: @Peter the array check is unnecessary, because if `icd9s` is `nil`, then `[icd9s count]` will return 0, and the `if()` condition will fail.  I agree though on the semantics of checking that the count is exactly 1.

Comment: @Dave DeLong: You can leave out testing the array by testing its count, but either way, the documentation says “you should always check [whether] the return value is `nil` … before attempting to do anything with the NSError object”. In this case, I would remove testing `err` (and I would still explicitly check that the array is not `nil`, but that's my own style), and add an `else` clause that presents the error.

Comment: Thanks for the tips you guys, all good tips for coding style, I will have to make sure that it is a count of 1 and not greater than 0, I had made the rookie mistake of thinking my database would have been created completely according to plan. But I haven't had any errors with that yet, any thoughts on why this might leak memory? It is definitely keeping some quite large variables alloced according to Instruments. I am not very good at reading Instruments data though. Also, @Dave DeLong, I would like to thank you for your CSV parsing code. It is used to pass the data 'uniqueID' to this function

Comment: @Kristian K glad you're finding it useful :)  As for leaking, there's nothing in the code you posted that would indicate a leak.  Perhaps you're retaining the return value of this method and not releasing it somewhere?

Comment: @Dave DeLong Hmm, I looked and I couldn't find any place I retain that value. I check that it is nil before I set it to the return value of this function and after I have set it I make sure to release it after I am done with it. Maybe I am just bad at reading Instruments data, but even when I isolate the code to just running that portion through the loop of 1459 items it continually increases the memory when about every 200 items it is supposed to clean up after itself and start over again with hopefully fresh memory. Oh well, I'll try to optimize some other code, Thanks!

Comment: @Kristian K: Use the Leaks instrument; it will tell you exactly what you are leaking. If it doesn't say anything, then you are not leaking memory, by a strict definition, but piling it up (and continuing to know about it, which is why Leaks wouldn't show it) without releasing it. For that, use heap shots. http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/ Either way, once you find the leaked/abandoned objects, you can get Instruments to show you what needs to release them that hasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Leaks template in Instruments to hunt down the leak(s). Your current code may be just fine once you fix them. The leak(s) may even be somewhere other than code.

Other problems:

- Using [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18-SW1) will make the loop over the array (1) faster and (2) much easier to read.
- Don't send `release` to an autorelease pool. If you ever port the code to garbage-collected Cocoa, the pool will not do anything. Instead, send it `drain`; in retain-release Cocoa and in Cocoa Touch, this works the same as `release`, and in garbage-collected Cocoa, it pokes the garbage collector, which is the closest equivalent in GC-land to draining the pool.
- [Don't repeat yourself.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) You currently have two `[pool release];` lines for one pool, which gets every experienced Cocoa and Cocoa Touch programmer really worried. Store the result of your tests upon the name in a Boolean variable, then drain the pool before the condition, then conditionally return the object.
- Be careful with variable types. `-[NSArray count]` returns and `-[NSArray objectAtIndex:]` takes an `NSUInteger`, not an `int`. Try to keep all your types matching at all times. (Switching to fast enumeration will, of course, solve this instance of this problem in a different way.)
- Don't hide releases. I almost accused you of leaking the fetch request, then noticed that you'd buried it in the middle of the code. Make your releases prominent so that you're less likely to accidentally add redundant (i.e., crash-inducing) ones.

Comment: Good tips, but I would like to clarify: I have two releases of the pool because they both end in a return, could you make yourself a little more clear on why I shouldn't have two of them? Also, the fetchrequest was released after it was last used, should I release it earlier than that?

Comment: @Kristian: You shouldn't have two releases for one pool because you may be able to hit both of them. It's common for the code to start out right, as you have it, then be made wrong later by making a return conditional (or unconditional, causing a leak) or replacing it. Not repeating yourself in the first place avoids this problem. You need to rearrange the flow as I suggested in order to have exactly one statement that drains the pool and to ensure that it always happens.

Comment: As for releasing the fetch request, my suggestion is to release it prominently, not bury the release in the middle of other code. You can't release it any earlier because you use it in the immediately preceding statement. You can autorelease it, however, and that's what I do: Autorelease (nearly) every object immediately upon creation.